# PHP OOP Function Precedence

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism

In OOP PHP, if I have a function defined in the parent class, and a modified version in the child class, and I call it from an instantiated object of the child class, will it use the child class's version of the function?

I am pretty sure it will, but I just wanted to double-check, as there's no way for me to check within a running application.

Comment: Yes, google for "polymorphism" or see this wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming#PHP.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, a function is called "method" once it belongs to a class.

Comment: Wow looking back I can't believe I ever didn't know this - it is so second nature to me now.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it absolutely will.

If you want to use the parent's version too, you must call parent::the_func() within the child's override of that function.

You must also call a parent's constructor if you override the constructor in the child.  It is not called automatically.